# yocto RDEPENDS Error when program include libgpiod

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm running a project that uses `yocto` to produce a version of Linux.

The image must contain a program developed with eclipse CDT which uses the one contained in the SDK as a `toolchain` and I have added a recipes called isabusrun.bb which includes this application.

Under these conditions the bitbake procedure ends successfully producing a valid image.

Then when I extended the program
which requires adding the libgipiod library to the project, the `bitbake` procedure fails with this message:

```
ERROR: isabusrun-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/ISABus/ISABusRun contained in package isabusrun requires libgpiod.so.2()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_isabusrun? [rdeps-file]
ERROR: isabusrun-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
```

I added version 2.0.2 to the `libgpiod` recipes but the error still shows up.

What should I do to resolve the error.

I tried to add this line into the isabusrun.bb,

```
RDEPENDS_isabusrun += " libgpiod.so.2()(64bit)"
```

and also

```
RDEPENDS_isabusrun += " libgpiod.2.0.2"
```

and get this other error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'libgpiod.so.2()(64bit)' (but /opt/yocto/dunfell-5.x.y/IEC-8/../layers/meta-simde/recipes-ISABusRun/ISABusRun/isabusrun.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'libgpiod.so.2()(64bit)' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['libgpiod.so.2()(64bit)']
NOTE: Runtime target 'isabusrun' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['isabusrun', 'libgpiod.so.2()(64bit)']
```

What can I do to solve this error.